# Por qué no se conecta LetsChat a MongoDB

Tags: kubernetes

estoy intentando hacer un despliegue y servicio de MongoDB y letchats pero toma el status de exited, porque no logra conectarse

2024-02-22 12:40:20 MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect

despliegue letschat

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: letschat
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: letschat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: letschat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: letschat
        image: sdelements/lets-chat:latest
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
```

Servicio:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: letschat
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: letschat
  ports:
    - name: service-http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: http
```

Despliegue MongoDB

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
```

Servicio:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

estoy usando kubernetes kubectl

> kubectl get services
> NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
> kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1               443/TCP          14m
> letschat     LoadBalancer   10.97.179.215   localhost     8080:30739/TCP   12m
> mongodb      ClusterIP      10.103.68.96            27017/TCP        13m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está relacionado con el servicio de LetsChat, ya que está definido como `type: LoadBalancer`. Normalmente, este tipo de configuración se realiza en un clúster desplegado en la nube, donde se asigna automáticamente un balanceador de carga con su respectiva IP pública. Sin embargo, al observar el comando `kubectl get services` que compartes, notamos que la dirección IP de este servicio se muestra como localhost.

```
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)       AGE
kubernetes ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP       14m
letschat   LoadBalancer 10.97.179.215   localhost     8080:30739/TCP  12m
mongodb    ClusterIP    10.103.68.96    <none>        27017/TCP     13m
```

Si estás en un entorno local, podrías cambiar el tipo a `ClusterIP` o `NodePort`.

La definición del service quedaría de esta manera:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: letschat
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: letschat
  ports:
    - name: service-http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: http
```

Posterior a eso para acceder por medio del navegador ejecutas este comando:

```
kubectl port-forward service/letschat 8080:8080
```

En el navegador escribes esto:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080` o `http://localhost:8080`